# Home page not displaying on my website

Tags: magento, frontend

My site was working fine all of a sudden front end disappeared.

I am not hardcore programmer but can do a bit here and there.

Pls guide me out of this issue

Site is www.kraftseeds.com

Comment: execution stops by `<div class="top-cart">` , try to check why it stopped there.

Answer (score 1):

Enable Developer mode.  Add this to your .htaccess file:

```
SetEnv MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE "true"
```

You may also want to enable display errors in index.php:

```
 ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

The best way I have found to debug is with X-Debug in a local environment.  You can also use log files to help debug in a production environment, if your unable to run X-Debug in the environment.

I've got a more detailed posting here:

http://www.molotovbliss.com/debugging-tips-and-tricks-with-magento-commerce

Consider also installing [XDebug](http://xdebug.org/)